# same external javascript link to many files

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a web app, where i am facing a problem. The problem is, I have multiple pages, to which i have linked one external javascript file. For example i have `page1.html, page2.html and page3.html` and to all of them i have added external javascript file `script.js`. The problem is , some of my javascript is global, as it loads directly when the page loads, without being called like a function. In this script I have referenced some DOM elements, from `page1.html` but when i visit `page2.html` i get errors in console, that is because the DOM of `page1.html` is still accessed by the  `script.js` is there any way, that i load specific part of script for each page from the one `script.js` file, or simply relevant part of script will be loaded from that `script.js` file for each page.

Moreover, i have have seen external javascript links likes this at many places :

**https://www.careem.com/sites/all/themes/careem/js/splash.js?p2g189**

in which you can notice that after `splash.js` **?** sign is used and some digits, is it something that can help me ?

Comment: Do page1.html, page2.html, and page3.html have the same origin?

Comment: What you mean by the same origin @guest271314

Comment: http://example.com/page1.html, http://example.com/page2.html, where http://example.com is the origin

Comment: yes indeed @guest271314

Comment: `if (document.querySelector("someSelector") { /* run script for that element */ }` - I cannot see how you would get errors because the dom element is "still accessed"

Comment: You could simply create three distinct files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the HTML documents are served from the same origin you can check the `.pathname` of `location`

```
// global variables for all pages here
const g = "global";

if (location.pathname.indexOf("page1.html") > -1) {
  // do stuff
}

if (location.pathname.indexOf("page2.html") > -1) {
  // do stuff
}

if (location.pathname.indexOf("page3.html") > -1) {
  // do stuff
}
```

If you are trying to access variables at different browsing contexts at the same origin you can use `localStorage` or a `SharedWorker` to communicate between browsing contexts if or when more than one of the documents is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions I can see.

Either move the document specific code out of the global script and put it into the HTML files inline, using `<script> code here </script>` (or add a secondary external script).

Or you can add an identifier to your pages, like `<body id="page1">` and run the code conditionally based on the `id`.

```
if (document.getElementById("page1")) {
  // code specific to page1.html
}
```

Comment: and what does that argument mean after the .js @Chris G

Comment: @NadeemAhmad I guess it's basically a hack; if a random string is appended to the script's url, the only effect is that the browser will never load a cached version but will always request the script from the server (since file caching is based on the URL).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create something that mimics a *“compiler directive”* as follows:

For example, you can choose either **document.location** or **document.title** to figure out which page has loaded so in your script you can go...

```
var Page=document.location;


if (Page.indexOf('page1')>-1) {

 // JS instructions for page 1

} else 

if (Page.indexOf('page2')>-1) {

 // JS instructions for page 2

} else 

if (Page.indexOf('page3')>-1) {

 // JS instructions for page 3

}
```

And so forth...